# flink 1.16 sink doris using flink-doris-connnect-1.14 package ,why run slowly?

Tags: http, jdbc, apache-flink, data-warehouse, apache-doris

I am using Flink version 1.16 and have incorporated the Flink Doris Connector 1.14 package through Maven. When attempting to sink a batch of data containing 30,000 records into the Doris database, the process takes approximately 3 minutes. Surprisingly, when I switch to Flink version 1.13, the same operation completes in just around three seconds.

I expect the data sinking process to Doris using Flink 1.16 to be completed within seconds, not minutes, similar to the performance observed with Flink 1.13.

I did not encounter this issue when using Flink 1.13. I have attempted to investigate the problem by checking version compatibilities between Flink and the Doris Connector, examining configuration changes, and utilizing performance monitoring tools. However, I have not found a solution to the problem.

Could you please provide guidance on resolving this performance discrepancy and achieving faster data sinking times with Flink 1.16 and the Doris Connector 1.14?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: the following is sink return infomation.


load Result {
    "TxnId": 61003202,
    "Label": "_0_bb636d1b-eeae-4ad6-9f4e-b25cdfd3863a",
    "TwoPhaseCommit": "false",
    "Status": "Success",
    "Message": "OK",
    "NumberTotalRows": 5,
    "NumberLoadedRows": 5,
    "NumberFilteredRows": 0,
    "NumberUnselectedRows": 0,
    "LoadBytes": 4426,
    "LoadTimeMs": 184700,
    "BeginTxnTimeMs": 0,
    "StreamLoadPutTimeMs": 3,
    "ReadDataTimeMs": 0,
    "WriteDataTimeMs": 184677,
    "CommitAndPublishTimeMs": 18
}

Answer (score 0):

Using mis-matched versions of Flink connectors is never a good idea. You can download a version of the Doris connector built for Flink 1.16 from GitHub: https://github.com/apache/doris-flink-connector/releases